# how to target css for ie9 only?

Tags: css

I need to use css for ie9 to be `float: left;` but for all other browsers it should be `float: none;`. So, I tried the following which doesn't work:

```
li{
  float: none !important;
  float: left !important \9;
}
```

How can I target to IE9 only. I would prefer without including external css for this single line of css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use like this:

```
li{
  float: none !important;
  float: left \9 !important;/* \9 is used after left not after important*/
}
```

`!important` should always be at the end.

Comment: You should avoid using !important

Comment: @Sidsec9 In some cases, we need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

As you are defining css style, then `!important` should be at end.
Try this

```
 float: left \9 !important;
```

Or you can use conditional comments

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<style>
Special instructions for IE 9 here
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this -

```
<!--[if IE 9]><!-->        
    //your style or script
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: `gte`: **g**reater **t**hen (or) **e**qual. you are looking for `[if IE 9]`